# Strange issue with Vue2 child component object v-for list render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent component that contains an array and an object:

```
    data() {
        return {
            products: [],
            attributes: {},
        }
    },
```

When my parent component is loaded, it gets some AJAX data and populates the variables:

```
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/requests/getProducts/' + this.currentCategory).then(response => {
            this.products = response.data;
            this.createAttributes(); // runs some methods to populate the attributes object
        });
    },
```

I then have a child component that I will use to display the attributes. Code from parent template:

```
    <search-attributes :attributes="attributes"></search-attributes>
```

I have the props declared in my child component:

```
    props: ['attributes'],
```

So far so good, I can console log the data from parent and child...

Problem is when I try to `v-for` the attributes in the child component, it simply returns nothing:

```
/////////////// this does not render anything ///////////////

<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(value, key) in attributes">
            {{ key }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, if I pass both the products and attributes variables to the child component, and render products in the child component, attributes will start working!

```
/////////////// this works /////////////
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(value, key) in attributes">
            {{ key }}
        </div>
    {{ products }}
    </div>
</template>
```

What the heck is going on?

Do you need to see my parent methods?

Comment: try make attributes computed property and prop it down to the children?

Comment: can you just dump `attributes`  in your template to see what is going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I expect you are running into a [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). Vue cannot detect when you add properties dynamically to an object. In this case, you begin with an empty `attributes` object. If you add properties to it without using $set, then Vue does not understand a change has occurred and will not update the DOM.

Update the `createAttributes` to use [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set).

The reason it works when you pass `products` is Vue *can* detect the change you make (`this.products = response.data`), so it renders the DOM, which shows the latest `attributes` as a by product.

Comment: thanks for the answer - spot on. Took me a while to figure out how to get it working with $set, but all good now. Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: actually, I thought I had $set working, but it turns out it was not collecting the data correctly and now I am back to square one with it. I created a new thread about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190211/vue2-using-set-does-not-fix-change-detection-caveat-when-using-push-on-object