# Vue2 using $set does not fix change detection caveat when using push() on object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Following on from this issue: [Strange issue with Vue2 child component object v-for list render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186256/strange-issue-with-vue2-child-component-object-v-for-list-render)

I have a function which loops through an array `products`, which takes certain values and adds them to an object called `attributes`. I need to use `this.$set` to update my `attributes` object to make sure that Vue can detect the update.

My functions look like this:

```
//// checks if the value exists in the object to avoid adding duplicates

        doesItExist: function(key, value) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.attributes[key].length; i++) {
                if (this.attributes[key][i] == value) return true;
            }
            return false;
        },


//// if the value does not exist, then add it to the object

        pushIfNotExists: function(key, value) {
            if (!this.doesItExist(key, value)) {   // returns true/false
                this.$set(this.attributes[key], key, this.attributes[key].push(value));
            }
        },


//// main function looping through the original products array to extract attributes

        createAttributes: function() {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < this.products[i]['attributes_list'].length; j++) {
                    let attributeName = this.products[i]['attributes_list'][j]['attribute_name'];
                    if (!this.attributes[attributeName]) {
                        this.attributes[attributeName] = new Array();
                    };
                    this.pushIfNotExists(attributeName, this.products[i]['attributes_list'][j]['value']);
                }
            }
            console.log(this.attributes);  // outputs expected object
        },
```

The problem I have is that in my child component, the attribute data is still not being rendered, which means this must not be working correctly (even though my console log shows the data is there).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It wasn't clear from the original question that `attributes` is derived from `products` (to me at least). Given it is, however, it might be worthwhile to convert it to computed property instead of a data property, which should also solve your reactivity issue in the same way properly using $set would.

Comment: @Bert thanks for the heads up. I tried this and then got it to work by using $parent.computedProperrtyName in the child component. I did try passing the computed prop as a prop from parent to child component in the normal manner, but could not get it to work for some weird reason..